# C, Dividing a string into string by whitespaces with pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers

I want to divide a string into strings by whitespaces with pointers. I wrote the code below, but it does not work. Do you have any idea?

```
    char sentence [] = "Thank you very much";
    char * words [4]; //number of words
    int i=0, charCounter=0, wordCounter=0;
    while(sentence[i]){

        char temp [5]; //maximum character count

        while(sentence[i] != ' ' && sentence[i] != '\0'){
            temp[charCounter] = sentence[i];
            charCounter++;
            i++;
        }

        temp[charCounter] = '\0';
        words[wordCounter] = &temp[0];
        wordCounter++;
        charCounter = 0;
        i++;
    }

    //there I want to write first word to check
    int k;
    for(k=0; k<12; k++)
        printf("%c ", *(words[0]+k));
```

Comment: You want to generate an array or just display the tokens?

Comment: Please elaborate on the "it does not work" part.

Comment: I do not want to use ready functions. And I want to generate an array. Do you see the bug?

Comment: [Implement strtok in C](http://fengl.org/2013/01/01/implement-strtok-in-c-2/)

Comment: `char temp [5];` is small and local scope. also `&temp[0]` is same address.

Comment: All your words are the same local variable `temp`, which will be overwritten and isn't even in the outermost scope of `main`.

Comment: Why do you use a loop with some fixed rage pulled from thin air when you want to print the first word? Sholdn't that be just `printf("%s\n", words[0]);`?

Comment: @newest member: find running example below :)

Answer (score 2):

I think there isn't too much wrong aside from your output loops:

```
// write word by word
int k;
for(k=0; k < wordCounter; k++)
    printf("%s ", words[k]);

// write first word byte by byte
k;
for(k=0; ((words[0])[k])!=0; k++)
    printf("%c", (words[0])[k]);
```

Check this this [code pad example](http://codepad.org/LoxcHCot) based on your code above.

Only thing I changed was to allocate memory for `words` and copy the string using `strcpy:`

```
words[wordCounter] = malloc(sizeof(char) *(charCounter +1));
strcpy(words[wordCounter], &temp[0]);
```

Otherwise you assign always the same address (compare [wrong example](http://codepad.org/zN6qINxl)).

Answer (score 1):

`char temp[5]` not need to save the start address of the word.
like as follows

```
char sentence [] = "Thank you very much";
char *words[sizeof(sentence) / 2] = {0};
int i=0, wordCounter=0;

while(sentence[i]){
    while(sentence[i] == ' '){
        ++i;//skip space
    }

    if(sentence[i] == '\0')
        break;
    words[wordCounter++] = &sentence[i];//set top of word

    while(sentence[i] != ' ' && sentence[i] != '\0'){
        i++;//skip word
    }
}

int k;
for(k=0; k<wordCounter; k++){
    while(*words[k] != ' ' && *words[k] != '\0')
        printf("%c", *words[k]++);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***You are adding a 6th char to an array of size 5!***
Thats the error!
**Also! You never reset the counter to 0, so as you keep going through words, you keep increasing the index added to temp as well**

EDIT: I saw the temp[5]; above the while loop xD my Mistake!\

I believe your error lies in never declaring the temp[] array. In C, you must always provide an array with its size, as well.

Add this the line after you define sentence:

```
    char temp[strlen(sentence)];
```

Also, a space and whitespace are two very different things. 
**Not all spaces are literally just a space!**
However, to get a more accurate reading of any kind of space, using the function isspace, like so, is a much better practice:

```
    while ((isspace(&sentence[i]) != 0) && (sentence[i] != '\0'))
```

hope this helps! :)